# Returning the height of a node in an ordered tree in Python

Tags: python, tree, nodes

I'm new to Python and am trying to return the height of a node in an ordered tree in python. Here is the code I have:

```
def Height(node, T):
    if Is_OrdLeaf(T) and node == OrdRoot(T):
        return 0
    else:
        heights = []
        for x in Children(node, T):
            heights += [Height(x, T) + 1]
        return max(heights)
```

But, when I run this code with a tree I get

> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

All of the called functions work and therefore, heights shouldn't be empty. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be obvious from your error, but you are taking the `max` of an empty list. You should check whether `heights` is empty and return 0 if it is.

Comment: I'm really wondering why heights is empty. Why isn't it adding the given things to heights? I know for certain that Children() and OrdRoot() work, and that I'm using a valid node and tree.

Comment: If your node is a leaf node, it has no children.

Answer (score 0):

```
heights = []

def height(t, level=0):
    if not t.children:
        heights.append(level)
    else:
        for c in t.children:
            height(c, level+1) 
    return max(heights)
```

Comment: It isn't a binary tree. Therefore, I don't really have a left or a right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to test this for you, but you've omitted the tree class.  Is it a standard package of some sort?

```
else:
    return max([Height(x, T) for x in Children(node, T)])
```

If you have a large tree, it might work even better to replace the list with a generator comprehension (change the brackets to parentheses).